# Some tutorial examples not working

Tags: javascript

in this tutorial example it says that there should be an output of 3 notification messages.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Chapter 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Here’s another basic page</h1>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
var ball = {
“color”: “white”,
“type”: “baseball”
};
ball.weight = 15;
for (var prop in ball) {
alert(ball[prop]);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I try it all I get is a page with the header "Here's another basic page"

hi I am just using notepad to edit the html files. But now to update I changed the file to be exactly like an earlier example which is just alert("Hello"); in the script. The file still does not work yet the earlier file works. can anybody think why this would be(I have checked through the files and I mean they are exactly identical other than the name of the files).
I am using a apache server configured to my local IP address and PHP and MySQL also running the files through IE10. The tutorial examples are from PHP,Mysql,javaScript and html5 all in one for dummies

Thanks guys I wrote it out a second time in a new file and it didn't work tried your suggestions and still nothing. Then wrote it out a third time and it worked both in its original form and with your suggestions. So I am putting it down to it just doesn't like me. lol

Comment: Maybe the fault is of the quotes you used. Try removing them and use single quotes( **'** ) or the double quotes( **"** ) instead

Comment: Those quotes `“` look shifty, try normal ones `"` (Edit: ah, LightStyle beat me to the punch)

Comment: Copying and pasting code does not always work ;) And learn [how to debug JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: Please get into the habit of testing with the JavaScript Console visible (F12 in IE or Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+K in Firefox).  That will show you the errors that your code is generating.

Comment: The example works if you change to normal or single quotes. Use jsfiddle when you do this sort of thing. It will give you hints as to what's wrong with your script if you click on "JSHint" at the top: http://jsfiddle.net/hj7Xq/

Comment: Which tutorial are you reading?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know what is your editor but you have a problem with your " and ' caracters

change your `“` and `’` to a normal `"` and `'` and it's working.

Comment: You have bad quote en your <script type=”text/javascript”> too.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the weird single and double quotes with "standard" ones, and also, when you create your Object:

```
var ball = {
“color”: “white”,
“type”: “baseball”
};
```

should be:

```
var ball = {
color: “white”,
type: “baseball”
};
```

color and type should not be in quotes, as they are variable names. Remove those quotes. Let us know if this works or if you're getting any other problems!

Just replacing the quotes with "normal" quotes, though, and leaving the quotes around the Object's variables seems to work as well, upon testing.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). This is a JavaScript object defined by an object literal and has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling excuse my using the wrong terminology. I'll edit the post as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Here is the "fixed" code (http://jsfiddle.net/tRgzY/), this was a problem of quotes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Chapter 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Here’s another basic page</h1>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
var ball = {
  'color': 'white',
  'type': 'baseball'
};

ball.weight = 15;
for (var prop in ball) {
    alert(ball[prop]);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```